# how to convert the list to dictionary where first list is key and second list is value in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I was trying following question [image]

I tried all my best but got stucked at the end part to convert the list to dictionary given in question above i.e `{1.3:[1.2,1.4]}`
here is how i did my solution for above question.

```
lst=[]
l=[1.3]
k=[1.2,1.4,1.5,1.6,2.3,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.2,5.4,5.8]
for x in range(len(l)):
    for z in range(len(k)):
        b=k[z]-l[x]
        if b>0.1:
            l.append(k[z])
        elif b<=0.1:
            print(lst.append(k[z]))
print(lst)
print(l)
```

how can I convert the list to dictionary at the end? ie {1.3:[1.2,1.4]}

Comment: Don't post images of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this,

```py
lst=dict() # create an empty dictionary
l=[1.3]
k=[1.2,1.4,1.5,1.6,2.3,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.2,5.4,5.8]
for x in range(len(l)):
    lst[str(l[x])] = [] # create a new dict entry with a key from l and an empty list
    for z in range(len(k)):
        b=k[z]-l[x]
        if b>0.1:
            l.append(k[z])
        elif b<=0.1:
            print(lst[str(l[x])].append(k[z]))  # add to the empty list inside the dictionary of corresponding entry in l that you are checking with
print(lst)
print(l)
```

```
{'1.3': [1.2, 1.4]}
[1.3, 1.5, 1.6, 2.3, 3.4, 3.6, 3.8, 4.2, 5.4, 5.8]
```

Comment: it is ok but what if the list value gets changed this method wont work i mean if 1.3 gets changed to 2.2 the answer is illogical

Comment: it will still work, nothing is hard coded...`str(l[x])` this sets the key to `1.3` or whatever value you have in `l`

Comment: i did this new way check  once

Answer (score 0):

I finally used `fromkey()` method and it solved my question

```
new_dict=[]
compare_value = 0.1
list_main=[1.3]
test_set=[1.2,1.4,1.5,1.7,2.3,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.2,5.4,5.8]
for x in range(len(list_main)):
   for z in range(len(test_set)):
       diff=test_set[z]-list_main[x]
       if diff>compare_value:
           list_main.append(test_set[z])
       elif diff<=compare_value:
           new_dict.append(test_set[z])
           dictionary=dict.fromkeys(list_main, new_dict)
print('dictionary----',dictionary)
print('list-------',list_main)
```

Comment: It will work, but you are not using `lst` and also cannot work when `list_main` has more than 1 element